# Angular unit test with DOM manipulation

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, dom, angular7, karma-jasmine

Hi I would like to ask for help to test the function below. My approach is that I will be assigning `tr` to my tagName in my testcase to test the if conditions inside of it.

**The function in my TS file is**:

```
  domEles : any;
  length : number = 0;

  moveToList(e : KeyboardEvent){
    if(document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == "tr"){
      this.domEles = document.querySelectorAll('#listTableBody > *');
      this.length = this.domEles.length;

      const activeEle = document.activeElement;
      const activeEleIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.domEles, activeEle);

      if((e.key == "ArrowDown" || e.key == "Down") && activeEleIndex < this.length - 1 ) {
        const nextElem = <HTMLElement>activeEle.nextElementSibling;
        nextElem.focus();
      } 

      if((e.key == "ArrowUp" || e.key == "Up") && activeEleIndex > 0) {
        const prevElem = <HTMLElement>activeEle.previousElementSibling;
        prevElem.focus();
      }
      this.detector.detectChanges();
    }
  }
```

**In my SPEC file, the approach is:**

```
    it('should trigger moveToList function',()=>{

        let doc = (this as any).document.activeElement;
        doc.tagName = "tr"

        let nextElem = spyOn(doc.activeElement, 'nextElementSibling');
        component.length = 5;
        component.domEles = 1;
        const e = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: 'ArrowDown'});

        component.moveToList(e);

        expect(nextElem).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
```

As I performed the test and checked, the if conditions inside the moveToList function is not taken/triggered by the this test.
Can you please help me guys for the best approach for the test case without modifying the actual codes in the function. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are 3 `if`, are you talking about `document.activeElement` ?

Comment: `tagName` is a read-only property, you cannot assign anything to it. Why don't you get a reference to the real `tr` elements and test all the cases including the edge ones (the beginning, and the end) and activate it using `focus()`? You can do that with `debugElement.query(By.css('#listTableBody > *:nth-of-type(position_of_the_element)'))` or `debugElement.query(By.css('#listTableBody > *:last-of-type'))` or even by getting the entire array of tr's using `debugElement.queryAll(By.css(''#listTableBody > *'))`.

Comment: hi @ShashankVivekm, yes I am referring to the first `if`

Comment: Hello @julianobrasil do I need to have a mock HTML or I'll just use the code you provided right away?

Comment: Just use the code, directly in your test file with fake data so Angular can build the table with, let's say, 4 tr's. Adjust the selector to what you want.

Comment: Hi @julianobrasil I used this for my test case,

`
let component: ComponentUnderTest;
it('Test 1', ()=>{

debugEl.query(By.css('tbody.table-body >*:nth-of-type(1)')).triggerEventHandler('focus', {});

debugEl.query(By.css('tbody.table-body >*:nth-of-type(1)')).triggerEventHandler('keydown', { key: 'ArrowDown' });

const e = { key: 'ArrowDown' };
component.moveRoleList(e)`

})`

But it does not test the if conditions of moveRoleList method. Sorry I don't know why I can't use the formatting for codes.

Comment: Two things: (1) have you checked whether your code found the intedend `tr`? I mean, did you tested whether `expect(debugEl.query(By.css('tbody.table-body >*:nth-of-type(1)')).toBeTruthy()` pass? (2) If the answer for (1) is "no", depending how you're building your table (maybe it's form an asynchronous datasource), maybe you need an 
`async()` test.

Comment: Hi @julianobrasil, thanks for the troubleshooting technique and I found out that the data needed in ngFor was not used/passed that is why my test failed. I tried the async but still it did not work. I will investigate this furthermore thank you so much.